# Strange bug: fread misses reading 3 bytes from binary file in the middle of the content

Tags: c++, byte, ifstream, fread, mismatch

fread missing 3bytes at position 0x380, 0x381 and 0x382 in the file.
bytes in decimal: 0, 13, 10
Both in msvc  and mingw compiler on windows 10x64, in both 32/64 compiled binary

Found solution: please close this "thread". Cheers
[ifstream read and fread not returning same data, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323321/ifstream-read-and-fread-not-returning-same-data-c)

Answer (score 3):

You most likely didn't open the file in binary mode, by giving the right parameter.

If you did, please clarify this in your question.

Comment: Specifically, the numeric values 13 followed by 10, when read from a text file, are the Windows representation of an end-of-line character. When read as text the two values turn into a **single** character, `'\n'`.